# Create a Turing machine for this interactive game

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, computation-models

Given two players $A, B$ and some natural number $n \ge 2$, let $\#(A,B,n)$ denote the following algorithm:

> $A$ thinks of some number $a \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$
>
> Until the game ends:
>
> > $B$ thinks of some number $b \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$
> >
> > $B$ tells $b$ to $A$
> >
> > If $a = b$ then the game ends

Is there a way to represent this algorithm on a Turing machine?

I have read articles on the Internet about the Interactive Proof systems, abstract models that:

1. allow games between two players
2. provide the privacy involved in storing the variable $a$
3. are reducible to Turing machines

However, I have seen that these systems only allow for a polynomial number of interaction rounds between parts. This way, $B$ could just repeatedly tell $A$ some number $q > n$ regardless of $a$, rendering the use of *this* system (in my opinion) impossible.

P.S. I am sorry for my bad English. It is not my native language.

Comment: Sure.  There may be more than one way to represent this as a Turing machine.  I encourage you to tell us more, to help us help you.  What are your goals?  What are your criteria for evaluating possible answers?  What is the motivation -- why are you asking?  What do you plan to do with an answer?  Why Turing machines?

Comment: Hi there, @D.W. . My goals are the following: [1] to determine the actual problem type this algorithm solves (does it solve a statement corresponding to a decision problem?, a counting problem? etc.) and [2] to take the following specific restriction of the problem: "B cannot repeat numbers or tell numbers outside bounds " (notice how all instances of #(•) halt now) and prove some membership relations between the restricted problem version and some of the corresponding main complexity classes (e.g. P, EXP, PSPACE etc. if our problem is a decision problem, #P if it is a counting problem etc.).